# update php and php-fpm in nginx server

Tags: php, wordpress, nginx, devops, amazon-linux-2

I have a requirement where I need to update the PHP and PHP-fpm to the latest version of the server. this server is hosted using Nginx and WordPress. We are using amazon Linux 2 when I disable php7.4 and enable php8 in amazon-Linux-extras and install I'm getting an error.
[php error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/h3SPT.png)

I have a couple of questions:
what happens when I uninstall and install PHP to the latest version does it after the site?
Do we have any workaround for this PHP error?

Thanks in advance.

I'm expecting a solution to update my PHP to the latest version without any issues. I have just started learning DevOps. I'm not familiar with these errors

Comment: Let me suggest performing a clean install of PHP 8 on a new server and methodically installing the WordPress, testing to make sure WP works correctly on the installed PHP version, install tools/extension, testing and then the custom application, testing ... . May want to take a snapshot after every successful testing step.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I removed php-json by `sudo yum remove php-json` and installed of php

sudo yum install php php-{pear,cgi,common,curl,mbstring,gd,mysqlnd,gettext,bcmath,json,xml,fpm,intl,zip}

Still the application works.

php-json is available in Amazon Linux Extra topic "php7.4"

```
$ sudo amazon-linux-extras install php7.4
```